# How do you convert one of your contributions to Mathwork's File Exchange to an add-on?

Tags: matlab, add-on

Is it possible to take one of your own contributions to Mathworks File Exchange (with code hosted on GitHub) and turn it into an add-on? And will any updates on GitHub be reflected in the Matlab add-on?

**Matlab Add-ons**

Matlab Add-ons help page [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/add-ons.html)

[image]

Comment: What is an add-on?

Comment: I have updated my question to provide a link to the Matlab add-on documentation